# Select a part of the property in chrome inspactor css panel

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

In one of my PCs when I use inspect tool in chrome, I can't select some part of a property or a value, so I have to retype all the value again. As many times as I click on the selected text, the caret doesn't go to the place I need and the selected text doesn't deselect.

the following picture shows what I want and what happens.

[image]

There is no problem in another PC.
Both are windows 10 64bit and google chrome 62.

Comment: If I click on the text again it turns into a normal caret. Or I usually use the keyboard arrows to get to the position I want.

Comment: @David It sounds like "As many [times as] I click on the selected text..." it just doesn't work. Weird.

Comment: @David Using arrow keys work but it takes more time. Clicking again doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try holding shift or control while clicking. Haven't tried it, but it may work. My guess is that it's simply a UX workflow that DevTools doesn't handle well.